# Validate property uniqueness on the database, but exclude the current record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I have an Organization model, which has an unique property 'username', I'm trying to add the validation rules for this property.

```
<?php namespace Cuadrangular\Users\Validator\Organization;

use Cartalyst\Support\Validator;

class OrganizationValidator extends Validator implements OrganizationValidatorInterface {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|unique:organizations,username'
    ];

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function onUpdate()
    {
        $this->rules['username'] .= ',{id},id';
    }

}
```

But the udpate keeps failing due to the unique constraint, if I manually change `{id}` to the id of the organization I'm trying to update it works. Any clues as to what might be wrong with the syntax?

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with https://github.com/cartalyst/platform and using the repository and validators generated via the workbench

Answer (score 0):

let say you have this example when update:

```
route.php
Route::put('update_profile/{user}', 'UserController@update');
```

On your request to validate will be like this:

```
return[
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username,' . $this->user
];
```

So laravel will check all the records for username except user with current id